# Swipelayout doesn't close

Tags: android

I have used com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar library for swiping my layout but my layout doesn't close `onHandRelease()` method. It will call when full layout is opend but in rare case it will not work. If I release my hand in between the layout will fully open instead of close.

I want the code for if user take away their hand then layout close. Please help me out. Here sample1 is my layout which I want to close.
My method code is:

```
@Override
public void onHandRelease(SwipeLayout layout, float xvel, float yvel)
{
   holder.sample1.close();
   ProductList.updateAdapter();
   count5 = count5_r = 0;

   holder.iv_add1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.iv_add2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.iv_add3.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.iv_add4.setVisibility(View.GONE);
   holder.iv_add5.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   holder.iv_rmv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.iv_rmv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.iv_rmv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.iv_rmv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
   holder.iv_rmv5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hard working on it, i got the answer. I know this is the silly answer but it works for me and this is the solution which I want.

Here in hand release method, set animation to swipe layout instead of closing it. `holder.sample1.animate().translationX(0).translationXBy(xvel);`